# how do i bring the root url when i refresh the page in react

Tags: reactjs

app.js
this is how i am navigating through the navigation

```
<div
  className="flex-one main-content-box"
  style={{ height: "calc(100% - 55px)" }}
>
  <div className="arrow-navigation" style={{ top: topPosition }}></div>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact render={() => <DashBoard store={main} />} />
    <Route path="/newprocess" render={() => <div>DEFG</div>} />
    <Route path="/release" render={() => <div>ABCD</div>} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

but when i refreshing the page the path remains the same for example suppose if i click on newprocess it goes to newprocess page but when i am refreshing the page it still remains in the same path but i want it to be in the root path which is "/"
How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

In this point, you can use event listener and change the route.

At your main route,

```
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", changeRoute);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", changeRoute);
    };
}, []);

const changeRoute = (e) => {
  history.push('/');
};
```

Comment: where shall i use the alertUser

Comment: Sorry. I edited the answer

Comment: where should i use this in app.js